# How could you combine these two scripts into one?

Tags: javascript

Totally new to Javascript. Looking to combine these two scripts into one, if possible:

```
<script>
(function() {
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.href = "https://www.example1.com";
document.querySelector("head").appendChild(link);
})();
</script>

<script>
(function() {
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.href = "https://www.example2.com";
document.querySelector("head").appendChild(link);
})();
</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did it work? If not, what errors or unexpected results did you see?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why didnt you just write it as one script to begin with? If you are trying to modularize your code you want to use a bundler like Webpack or Rollup

Comment: @p.s.w.g, I tried combining things as best I could without knowing javascript. Guesses.

Comment: @GifCo, Just trying to make it smaller, more efficient. I didn't write it as one script because I don't know how to write javascript.

Comment: @Ripcord yea so what made you think to split it up? The only thing you would have to do to keep it as one script is change your variable names to link and link2 so they dont collide. Also please use let instead of var.

Comment: @GifCo They were separate scripts. I just figured there must be a cleaner way to write it, and everything I did broke it. So...I figured I'd ask the smart folks here! I don't know what let or var are...since I don't code javascript. I appreciate the suggestions, but you might as well be offering suggestions on golf club selection and grip position to someone who can barely get through the windmill in mini golf. But thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have only a single function, and pass variables as parameters. Both functions you have pasted are basically identical:

```
 <script>
    function oneFunction(href){
      var link = document.createElement('link');
      link.rel = "stylesheet";
      link.href = href;
      document.querySelector("head").appendChild(link);
    }
    oneFunction("https://www.example1.com");
    oneFunction("https://www.example2.com");
 </script>
```

Comment: Might as well go with the cleanest version! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

similar script for your code

```
<script>
(function(){
   var headUrl = ["https://www.example1.com","https://www.example2.com"];
   headUrl.forEach(function(linkURL) {
      let link = document.createElement('link');
      link.rel = "stylesheet";
      link.href = linkURL;
      document.querySelector("head").appendChild(link);
   })
})()
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
(function() {
var link1 = document.createElement('link');
var link2 = document.createElement('link');
link1.rel = "stylesheet";
link1.href = "https://www.example1.com";
link2.rel = "stylesheet";
link2.href = "https://www.example2.com";
var head =  document.querySelector("head")
head.appendChild(link1);
head.appendChild(link2);

})();
</script>
```

Comment: I think `.appendChild(link1).appendChild(link2)` will try to nest the links. I.e. `<link ...><link ...></link>`